# C# OleDbConnection con set to timeout

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timeout, database-connection

I have an app that queries an Access database and shows the data. I want the connection(con) to timeout after 2 minutes. Does anyone have any suggestions on how i can code this?

this is what i have in the beginning

```
OleDbConnection con;
OleDbDataReader dr;
OleDbCommand cmd;

con.Open();
cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't share the connection, create the connection when you need and wrap it by `using block`,

if you need to set the timeout, you can set by using [**`ConnectionTimeout`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) property  in connection string (e.g. `".....;Connect Timeout=30"`

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(str, con))
{
   con.Open();
   using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Damith is close, but unfortunately the `ConnectionTimeout` property is read-only. You have to set the timeout in the connection string instead by using `... ;Connect Timeout=30;`. [Here's the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: And... apparently it's not always the provider allows the setting of `ConnectTimeout`, `Connect Timeout` or `Connection Timeout`  :(      I ended up setting the timeout at the SQL Server side. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Timeout parameters,

`OleDbCommand.CommandTimeout` Property - When you need time out during execution of the query

`OleDbConnection.ConnectionTimeout` Property - When you need time out whilemaking a connection