# How can I use timeout for try-catch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch, oledbconnection

I have a try-catch for oledbconnection like this:

```
try
{
        OleDbConnection Connection;
        using (Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=DATABASE:1521/orcl//orcl1;Persist Security Info=True;Password=PASS;User ID=USER"))
        {
            Connection.Open();
            v1 = 1;
            Connection.Close();
        }
}
catch (Exception)
{
        v1 = 0;
}
```

When I can't connect database, try going to catch and return `v1 = 0`. It's working but when connection waiting so much(for example 30-40  seconds), try trying to connect and page waiting so much.

I tried `Connect Timeout` for `oledbconnection` but does not working.

I need to use try for few secs, if any problem, need to go catch.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can make command object and then use CommandTimeOut property of the OleDBCommand object to set the timeout, or set database connection timeout.

Comment: Can you show me example please?

Comment: string sQuery=your query here
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, _Database.Connection);
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
int countRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Note: CommandTimeout sets timeout for execution of query.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using .net 4.5 then you can benefit the Task timeout and async await capabilities:

```
int timeout = 1000;
var task = SomeOperationAsync();
if (await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeout)) == task) {
    // task completed within timeout
} else { 
    // timeout logic
}
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238345/asynchronously-wait-for-taskt-to-complete-with-timeout)

In case you are stuck with .net 3.5 or older:

```
using System.Threading;

class Program {
    static void DoSomething() {
        try {
            // your call here...
            obj.PerformInitTransaction();         
        } catch (ThreadAbortException) {
            // cleanup code, if needed...
        }
    }

    public static void Main(params string[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(DoSomething);
        t.Start();
        if (!t.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))) {
            t.Abort();
            throw new Exception("More than 30 secs.");
        }
    }
}
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265412/set-timeout-to-an-operation)

Comment: Note that this is a general answer for any operation that you need to timeout. The OLE DB connections should support a timeout (specified in connection string) that works!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see 'Connect Timeout={seconds};" in your connection string.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843814/c-sharp-oledbconnection-con-set-to-timeout)

> the ConnectionTimeout property is read-only. You have to set the timeout in the connection string instead by using Connect Timeout=30;

and don't forget ';'

Comment: I tried `Connect Timeout=sec;` but it's not working.